# Enabling compression (Amazon EC2)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, compression, mod-deflate

I'm trying to enable compression on my EC2 instance by adding the following to my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Force compression for mangled headers.
# http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
# (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
#  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
#  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/ld+json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
```

I've checked my server's httpd.conf and `mod_deflate` is being loaded:

[image]

I'm running Apache 2.2.29

What else can I check to see what it's not working? :-/

Comment: Can you please let me know if you or someone added these as I don't have any modules loaded from default ? Oh I see now my modules are all loaded in conf.modules.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to enable `mod_filter`. Now it's working fine!